# Create two list from facts

Tags: prolog

I have these facts:
fact(1,'a').
fact(2,'b').
fact(3,'c').
fact(4,'d').

my goal is to create 2 lists: one for the ID and one for the strings.
So, something like this one:
fact(['a', 'b', 'c' , 'd'], [1, 2, 3, 4]).
but by a RULE.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way I know is with library([pairs](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.18%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/pairs.html%27%29%29)):

```
facts_lists(Ids, Atoms) :-
   findall(Id-Atom, fact(Id, Atom), Pairs),
   pairs_keys_values(Pairs, Ids, Atoms).
```

Comment: Thanks, this works very well.
Is it also possible count the pairs with this library?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly more involved solution if you don't have the `pairs` library available (e.g., you're using `gprolog`):

```
unzip( [], [], [] ).
unzip( [[L,R]|ListT], [L|LT], [R|RT] ) :-
    unzip( ListT, LT, RT ).

fact_lists( Ids, Atoms ) :-
    findall( [Id, Atom], fact(Id, Atom), FactList ),
    unzip( FactList, Ids, Atoms ).
```

So you'd call:

```
fact_lists( Ids, Atoms ).
```

And get:

```
Ids = [1,2,3,4]
Atoms = ['a','b','c','d']
```

Comment: the pair representation as [A,B] it's a bit cumbersome. A-B (exactly as used in library(pairs)) it's the preferred way in Prolog community.

Comment: I agree. I was only presenting an alternative not using pair. I was going to just show a custom pair type of approach, but chose this method, again, as an alternative. As I said at the beginning of my answer: "Here's a slightly more involved solution if you don't have the pairs library available." I've only been using `gprolog`, so I don't have "library(pair)", for example.

Comment: @mbratch CapelliC was pointing out that if you have two things, you would rather represent them as a "pair", `A-B`, than a list of two things. Your approach is otherwise perfectly fine. `[A, B]` is actually `.(A, .(B, []))`, so you can see why `A-B` is preferred. "Pair" in this context just means two separate things that need to be together for the time being; the dash is the conventional way of denoting a pair.

Comment: Thanks Boris. How would you suggest doing that in `gprolog`?

Comment: Unless you address me, I will not get your comment in my Inbox and might not react to it. Check out the source code of library(pairs) from the SWI-Prolog web page.

Comment: @Boris, I think the argument about representation of the A-B pairs in the OPs note depends upon whether they care about keeping that representation. Their goal was to get the list of Ids and Atoms, but did not mention whether the intermediate pair-value representation was important.

Comment: And this is why I said that your approach is perfectly valid. The point both CapelliC and I are trying to make (without much success) is that pairs are normally represented as `A-B`, not `[A, B]`, or `pair(A,B)`, or whatnot. The `A-B` representation is not only the most concise (and efficient), but also it is familiar to the eyes of a Prolog programmer, thus communicating intent much better than any of the other possibilities.

Comment: @Boris, please, I do understand your point about data representation. I hope you don't interpret my questioning as a lack of understanding. However, I was unaware that the `A-B` format was such a familiar idiom in Prolog programming.

Comment: For example `keysort` is a ISO-Prolog predicate which you'll find in most mainstream implementations (including GNU-Prolog). It works on a list of pairs Key-Value.